# Not able to translate "Look and Feel" Text

Tags: survey, qualtrics

I am having survey in multiple languages, and I have also provided custom "Next" and "Back" buttons which I have translated in the Library using "Look and Feel" message type.

I have no problem in other translations, but in this Next or Back, I am unable to display special characters.

For example:

- Zurück is displayed as: Zur`&uuml;`ck
- 戻る is displayed as: `<pre data-placeholder="Translation">戻る</pre>`

How do I display special characters in Next and Back button then?

I tried adding HTML, copy pasting Unicode characters in message but not able to achieve this.
I need a way to show special characters in Next and Back buttons as well.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the translated messages in Source [<>] mode. If you paste unicode characters they will get saved as html entities and will display correctly in your survey.